# Incorrect Tensor Values

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a 10x10 matrix and a vector with 10 elements. 10x10 matrix is randomly initialized with `tf.random_uniform`; 10-vector is a constant.

I multiply the vector and the matrix with `tf.matmul` and call the results *logits*. Then, I evaluate and print logits with `logits.eval()`.

Then, I get the max from logits tensor and substitute it with 1, and all else with 0's. I evaluate this tensor with `.eval()` and print the resulting tensor.

The output of evaluate is incorrect, in that the index for maximum value is not 1.

However, if I take the output of `logits.eval()` and define a constant and then run the same code and evaluate, the result comes out ok. Following is the code:

```
tf.set_random_seed(1)
beta = tf.random_uniform([100], dtype=tf.float32, name="beta", seed=2)
beta = tf.reshape(beta, [10,10])
res = tf.constant([[0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 3., 2., 1., 0., 0.]], dtype=tf.float32)
logits = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([1, 10]), name='logits')
sess1 = tf.Session()
sess1.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
logits = tf.matmul(res, beta)
print(logits.eval(session=sess1))
tf.where(
        tf.equal(tf.reduce_max(logits, axis=1, keepdims=True), logits), 
        tf.constant(1, shape=logits.shape), 
        tf.constant(0, shape=logits.shape)
    ).eval(session=sess1)
```

Output:

```
[[ 5.64927   11.539942  10.365061   6.367746  10.591797  10.503089
  11.0828085  7.0345297  8.477502   8.649068 ]]
array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

I think there's something that I'm not doing right but despite my spending significant amount of time debugging it, I'm not able to fix it. I'd appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common pitfall in Tensorflow. The problem is the way you define `beta` as `random_normal` but not as a variable. This will produce a *new* random `beta` with each `session.run`. Thus, the logits you print first are *not* the same you then do the 0-1 substitution with, since they result from multiplying a different beta with your constant vector. Defining `beta` to be a `tf.Variable` instead should fix this issue.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my issue, but I still have a slight confusion. I'm passing seed value with the initialisation, shouldn't this always result in the same values in different runs?

Comment: From the looks of it, no -- the way I understand [the seed documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/set_random_seed), setting the seed will allow reproducibility _across sessions_ (i.e. if you were to start a new session it should give you the same sequence of "random" values), but different runs within a session will still produce different values.